# Unable to launch Spyder after installation of PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, conda, spyder, python-sip

On installation of PyQt5 i'm unable to launch Spyder on Windows. When i tried to launch through the conda prompt, i get the following error,

```
File "C:\Users\sarshetty\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 132, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR as PYQT_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.7 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.8
```

I see the following for my sip and PyQt in the python terminal.

```
>>> import sip
>>> sip.SIP_VERSION_STR
'4.19.8'
>>> import PyQt5
>>> import PyQt5.Qt
>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v12.0 to v12.7 but the PyQt5.QtCore module requires API v12.8
```

I tried upgrading my sip, however that has not helped. Can anyone tell me what is happening and how i can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me

1. Uninstall the installed PyQt5 library with pip

```
pip3 uninstall pyqt5
```

2. Install PyQt5 with conda

```
conda install -c anaconda pyqt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing here but I think the error is referring to PyQt5-sip since the newest release is version 12.8.0

https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-sip/

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Anaconda comes with its own version of PyQt5, so you don't need to install it by running `pip install pyqt5` (which seems you did).

By doing that, you basically broke Anaconda and now you have to remove and reinstall it, sorry.

Comment: could you show how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall pyqt5(pip uninstall pyqt5) and then reinstall it version 5.11.3(pip install pyqt5==5.11.3)
After installing the new version it'll show an error msg but it will work anyways.
This has worked for me and my colleges.